# File open and read in AWS Glue with Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, file-io, aws-glue

I have a simple python code below. This is written in desktop, now I want to recreate this to aws glue or lambda, I have to read the testfile.csv from a s3 directory and put to txt just like below. how this open and read can be recreated in aws glue/lambda environment. Any input is appreciated.

```
filepath = testfile.csv
txt = open(filepath).read()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this. The first line store the file as byte object and second line convert it to string and store to txt.

```
object = s3client.get_object(Bucket='mybucket',Key='testfile.csv')
txt = (object['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using similar answers I managed to read a JSON file, and use a field value like this:

JSON file contents in the S3 Bucket:

```
{
    "myField1": myValue1,
    "myField2": myValue2,
}
```

Code:

```
MyBucket=s3://mybucketname/somepath/myfile.json
FileFrame = (
    glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        format_options={"multiline": False},
        connection_type="s3",
        format="json",
        connection_options={
            "paths": [MyBucket]
        },
        transformation_ctx="FileFrame",
    )
)
RawFile = FileFrame.toDF().collect()[0]
# Now you can use it
print(RawFile["myField1"])
print(RawFile["myField2"])
```